# android displaymetrics returns 2/3 of screensize

Tags: android, android-screen

i use displaymetrics to get the screen size of the device. in smartphone it works good but in tablet it returns 2/3 of the screen width and height. can anyone tell me why is that?

that's the code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int screenheight = metrics.heightPixels;
int screenwidth= metrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `getRealMetrics()` instead:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
```

This API was officially added in API 17, but in my limited testing it's worked correctly even on 4.0 devices, so it may have been a hidden API before that.

Official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealMetrics%28android.util.DisplayMetrics%29), though there seems to be more reasons that the other API doesn't do what you expect than the text there would imply.

If there are ICS devices that this API doesn't work on, you could also try the fallbacks mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17512853/642160).

Answer (score 0):

You are not scaling by the density.

Try this:

```
int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Also

```
(WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE).getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```