# Nexus-S/Galaxy SII 480x800 resolution shows 480x728 on genymotion emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I don't have a 480x800 device so I am using genymotion emulator instead. The specs for Nexus-S says 480x800 but when I get the size of the screen in the app it says 480x728? I was wondering if that's something that is happening on the actual device as well or it is just a bug in genymotion emulator?

```
@Override
public void onClick( View view )
{
    if ( view == null )
        return;

    View v1 = getActivity().findViewById( R.id.bg );
    Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "height:" + v1.getHeight() + " width:" + v1.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
```

I have these in my style.xml

```
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code where you get the screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in actual height and your view height is a height of software buttons bar at the bottom of the screen (it is 48 dp).

The correct way to determine actual screen height depends on device API version and described here: [How to get real screen height and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341041/how-to-get-real-screen-height-and-width?rq=1)

use the following snippet:

```
int screenWidth = 0;
int screenHeight = 0;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    Point size = new Point();
    try {
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        Log.i("error", "it can't work");
    }

} else {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
}
```

Comment: So, how do I get rid of those software buttons? is it also there on the actual device?

Comment: This is not applicable to the Nexus S as it has physical buttons.

Comment: Genymotion Nexus S emulator is not an actual device copy, it is just that OS image with some tweaks, and yes, it shows software menu buttons. Software buttons strip height is 48dp not 48px, for hdpi density it is 48 * 1.5 = 72 px.

Comment: There is no way to hide these software buttons on non-rooted device

Answer (score 0):

This is showing the dimensions of the Activity view. The width is right because that view spans the full width of the display. The height, however, is not the full resolution height because it is the full height, minus the height of the status bar, minus the height of the action bar. If you want the true resolution of the display, use the following code for API level 13 and up:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you want to support lower than API 13, you can use:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

Comment: I am disabling both actionbar and title. so I guess that's not the case... please refer to the edited question for code details.

Comment: Does the status bar still display?

Comment: Can you post the XML that defines R.id.bg

Comment: xml for the layout added.

Comment: Ok, this is strange. Can you run the above code to see if for some reason the overall dimension is wrong? If it returns the correct 480x800 resolution, I'm stumped.

Comment: Actually the code you suggested also returned 728x480. so I guess there is something wrong with the emulator itself.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! If my answer helped you reached this conclusion, please accept it.

Comment: After waiting for a long time and so much frustration, I was able to use android emulator. I set the device type to Nexus S and the values were 800x480. So the conclusion is that this is a bug with genymotion emulator.