# DisplayMetrics not returning exact height and width of the screen

Tags: android, textview, height, width

I have to add multiple `TextViews` dynamically.

Each `TextView` should fill the screen and the next `TextView` should be added beneath the first view and even it should occupy the entire screen .

I've used the following code to determine screen height and with at run time.

**Code snippet**

```
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++)
        {
            text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            text.setText(class.get(i));
            text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            text.setTextSize(40);
            text.setClickable(true);
            LL.addView(text);
        }
```

**Result**:

1st view occupies entire screen and it is extended to next screen.

When 2nd view added to `LinearLayout` little gap is left over at the top.

This scenario can be understood only with screenshots.

**Screenshots**:

[image: 1st]

[image]

[image]

slowly these screens are moving down.their height is increased by 30dp approx.

How could I get the exact height and width of the screen using DisplayMetrics.

**EDIT:**

Even by using [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23861333/4361127) screen occupies 30dp more than its height

Answer:

> After calculating the screen width and height substract the  height of Action bar from it.

This point is not mentioned. neither here nor in that duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.match_parent, LinearLayout.match_parent)` instead of new `LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)`

and also make your `TextView`
object `local` instead of `global`

```
TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I've done that.But it accepts only 1  `TextView`

Comment: make textview object local