# How can I get bezel height and width on Android programatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

If there is no api to get that, can I get the total height and width of the device which includes the bezel information?

Comment: "total height and width of the device" - Do you mean screen?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14342326/313870

Comment: Nope that doesn't give the bezel size included. According to google docs the actual device resolution is more then the one returned by the above api and the actual can be obtained through display.getmode.getPhysicalheight/width. However doing so still fails on my Samsung S9 which has 3 display modes but when I change to any of those yet only the highest resolution mode gets returned