# Force android screen Orientation depending on screen size

Tags: android, android-manifest, tablet, screen-orientation

I am writing an application that allows users to select various things on the screen.
On large 10 inch screens this looks best in landscape so I force landscape in the manifest file.

However, I want to make the application friendly for users of 8 (or 7) inch tablets as well. On these screen sizes the application should be forced in portrait mode.

Does anyone know how I can force the screen orientation depending on the screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out if the device is a 7, 8 or 10 inches tablet, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055458/detect-7-inch-and-10-inch-tablet-programmatically).

One way you can manipulate the device orientation is in every activity, after onCreate(), like this:

```
    // set the orientation of the device
    if(isTabletWith10Inches) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

Comment: Is possible to do it in manifest/xml? I don't want to do this at runtime