# Different UI for Tablet and Mobile

Tags: android, user-interface, tablet, smartphone

I am working with one Application for **Tablet** and **Mobile** mode.

I have confusion.

There is totally  different **UI** and **WEBAPI** for one screen only.

Can I make these changes in the **same app**?

Or

I have to create a **different application** for Tablet mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solve my question by Using below code.

**Create bool.xml file under app > src > main > res > values > bool.xml**

Same for **values**, **values-sw600dp**, **values-sw720dp**

**bool.xml** for **values**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

**bool.xml** for **values-sw600dp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

**bool.xml** for **values-sw720dp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Now do just following things.

```
// Global Variable
boolean isTablet;

//Get Value from values bool.xml file
 isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);

//Now check condition
if(isTablet){
      //Device is tablet
}else{
      //Device is mobile
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Just Create a new layout with same name for that particular page 
like

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Comment: I know that bro. This is possible if I have the same layout for tablet and mobile. But In my case, there is a totally different UI for tablet and mobile.

Comment: Its just for one activity right. Then you check programatically whether its a tab or mobile and divert your activity. Its better than creating 2 app I think.

Comment: How about adopt `fragment` too?

Comment: There is also too much other stuff like, Tablet mode should support rotation while mobile mode should only in portrait mode. WEB API is also for both screens. If tablet mode, then whole app should support rotation while in mobile mode, there is only portrait mode.

Comment: I think Its better to make Changes in same app than creating a new application. But you have to check programaticaly and divert to different fragments. If you are  building in same app you can reuse fragments if needed. I will suggest you to do in same app than a different one

Comment: @ChiragSavsani for the rotation, maybe you need to handle it in code: [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885288/force-android-screen-orientation-depending-on-screen-size).

Answer (score 0):

You can create layouts that have a min-width constraint. If goes like this:

XML Layout folder => New File => Layout Resource File =>

- Same name as other file
- Available qualifiers => Smallest width => (example) 600

Then go and make a layout that makes sense for a tablet. *Android  will pick the right XML for the screen size.