# Why is the second textview in the row is not displaying in the tablelayout?

Tags: android, popup, android-tablelayout

I'm displaying the data in the pop-up in tabular format. But some data in the row is not displaying. I'm not able to see the textview only. Below is my layout.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pageTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/vwVerticalColourBar"
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVisitTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#EDEDED" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvVisitStoreName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvVisitStoreAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="#333333"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In the above layout, the tvVisitStoreAddress textview is not at displaying. Please find the screen shot as below. Is this regarding the size of the row or something else.

[image: Current]

But actually, it should display as below. Please help me in this regard.

[image: Actual]

Comment: Just FYI, fill_parent is deprecated and should be replaced by match_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `LinearLayout` in the `TableRow` with the `TextView`s does not have it's `orientation` property set.

Just put `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Thanks for reply Anxgotta, i will try and let you know

Comment: kishore jethava also made a good point that I didn't notice.  You are restricting the height of the TableLayout.  Make sure that leaves enough space for the contents of the TableRows.  Try wrap_content first to get the format of the layout correct, then shrink it if you like and watch the results.

Comment: Ok, you mean to say give table layout height as wrap content first, then shrink it accordinly?

Comment: That's what I mean, yes. Apologies if I was unclear =)  Start with the TableLayout height as 'wrap_content' just to eliminate it as a possible issue.  Then get your TableRows looking correct.  Then go back to adjusting the TableLayout height to your liking if needed.

Comment: No problem, ok. In this case let my table layout be wrap content only. Because, the data inside popup may increase. Thanks for the help. It worked.

Comment: And also, one more thing i wanted to ask you. The date in the above picture, is actually a title, how to increase the size of that particular and make it center alignment. Could you shed me some lights in this regard AnxGotta

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  To get that title Text view text larger and centered you could do the following:  In the TextView xml, simply add android:gravity="center" and then change android:textSize="#sp" where # is the number of the text size... 16 or something.  You already have the TextVIew width as "fill_parent" so you just need to center the text using the android:gravity xml property. (UseChat if you need more help)

Comment: Ok AnxGotta, thanks a lot. I will try as you suggested. If i require any more details, i will ping you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92526/discussion-between-coders-and-anxgotta).

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set fix `height` of `TableLayout`

change `TableLayout` height `android:layout_height="50dp"` to `android:layout_height="100dp"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kishore, i will check and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Actually [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) height creates this problem . Just increase your `android:layout_height`

**How Do**

You can set `android:layout_height` as dynamically . You can use `DisplayMetrics` .And set Height respect to Device Height .

> [Detect 7 inch and 10 inch tablet programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055458/detect-7-inch-and-10-inch-tablet-programmatically)