# Publish Android application for 7 and 10 inch tablet only

Tags: android

How can I publish an application for 7 and 10 inch tablets only on playstore? I've a specific requirement to publish the application for those 2 tablets only. Is there any code or restriction on Play Console through which I can restrict other tablets and devices? I have searched in Play Console but I cannot target specifically those 2 sizes only.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en this might help

Comment: There may not be any device ever manufactured whose screen size is *exactly* 7 inches or 10 inches.

Answer (score -1):

You can programmatically check the screen size using some Java code. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055458/detect-7-inch-and-10-inch-tablet-programmatically) goes into the details.

When your app gets launched, check the screen size of the device. If it doesn't match your requirements, you can simply not launch your app. This is however not an ideal solution.