# default resolution is lower than actual resolution of my device

Tags: java, android

i have used

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
cube.height=metrics.heightPixels;
cube.width=metrics.widthPixels;
```

to get height and width of my display but the resolution is low for my sony xperia p device which is qhd display. from this function i can only get height=569 px and width=320 px
i don't understand why this is showing lower. i think this is giving me virtual resolution than real one. i used simple view and ondraw method to draw the canvas.

please help.

Comment: How much does DisplayMetrics give for resolution and what are the actual pixel sizes of your screen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();     
Method mGetRawH = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
Method mGetRawW = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");
int rawWidth = (Integer) mGetRawW.invoke(display);
int rawHeight = (Integer) mGetRawH.invoke(display);
```

As quoted from a website [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991194/android-displaymetrics-returns-incorrect-screen-size-in-pixels-on-ics).

Comment: thanx this one shows the real resolution of my device. But i think the canvas got the virtual resolution i mean as i use `canvas.drawtext("..",320,0,paint)` the string just hides at left end since my device has 540 width so i guess it must be as little left than middle but it doesn't. its like canvas as lower ppi. i tried in another mobile with qvga display where it shows higher resolution than the original device and seems to draw canvas with high ppi. i don't get it. how can i draw canvas with real resolution of device.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with Canvas and how that works. I would recommend asking another question. Please accept and/or upvote my answer if it helped with this question though! Sorry I couldn't help on the canvas front.

Comment: What do you mean by the string hiding at left end? drawText takes pixel x and y as parameter where the text top left corner should be positioned. Are you sure your canvas is correctly positioned where you are drawing (width, height, coordinates)? A screenshot could be helpful here.