# Android Virtual Device metrics

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I created an Android AVD, have a look at the below screen shot.

[image]

When I pull metrics in debug I get the following specs.

[image]

Height = 888 but should be 960, why?

Comment: I think you have the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11004877/3390963