# Libgdx does not get the resolution correctly in Nexus 5

Tags: libgdx, width, screen, resolution

The screen resolution of the nexus 5 is 1920X1080, and Libgdx says it is 1794X1080. I'm using it in landscape mode, and libgdx is getting the height correct, but it reduces the width. I guess that is because is not counting the pixels of the navigation bar.

Is there any solution to make libgdx to detect  the width including the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get real display resolution you should check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991194/android-displaymetrics-returns-incorrect-screen-size-in-pixels-on-ics). But I think you may want to run your application in real fullscreen mode. That's it, without navigation bar. Just set [useImmersiveMode](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html#useImmersiveMode) to `true` in your AndroidApplicationConfiguration.

You can Read about Android immersive mode here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html#useImmersiveMode