# Android Screen size full screen

Tags: android, size, screen, pixel

I need to get the exactly size screen but i cant get it.

I tried this two different codes:

```
DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
height = display.heightPixels;
width = display.widthPixels;


Point size = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
height = size.y;
width = size.x;
```

In both cases the height its correct (1080) but the width its not correct. It must return 1920 but its returning 1794. Its a Samsung Galaxy S4 (1920x1080).
I have a full screen app, with no actionbar or navigation bar, etc. 
Why is happening this and how can ai get 1920. Im using API >= 14.

Greets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991194/android-displaymetrics-returns-incorrect-screen-size-in-pixels-on-ics

Comment: Tough I'm sure your code always returned valied values for me, but I was not in the full screen mode... maybe that's the problem

Comment: it says that on Android 4.2 or above this code dont work,

Comment: I've been using that code since... I don't know. API level 14 I guess, but have never seen any issues :((

Answer (score 2):

You can try with getRealSize instead of getSize ([getRealSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point)))

> ```
> Point size = new Point();
> getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
> height = size.y;
> width = size.x;
> ```

Comment: I need a solution to API 14. To use that code i need API 17. It works but i need to use API 14

Comment: You can do something like this
if(Build.VESION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODE.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    // use getRealSize
    Point size = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
    height = size.y;
    width = size.x;
} else {
    try {
     Method getHeight = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
     Method getWidth = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");
     width = (Integer) getHeight.invoke(display);
     height = (Integer) getWidth.invoke(display);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     width = display.getWidth();
     height = display.getHeight();
  }
}